# Add target attribute to anchor tags without id or class

Tags: javascript, html

I've got an input which allows users to add text with anchor tags for hyperlinks.  I'd like to keep it simple for the user so all they need to enter is `<a href="www.google.com">link</a>` but would love to add a `target` attribute to the tag systematically.

Is there an elegant way in JavaScript I can do this without having an ID associated with the tag?  (e.g. `getElementById` wont work here).  Other entries I found in stackoverflow address this but only when the anchor tag has an ID.

These links will, however, always have the same parent div class.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: You can use querySelectors

Comment: How are you adding user input to the content? That’s the code you should revise.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela user input is through a Zend form.  Generally I would agree with you, but in this case avoiding modification to that code may be the best option.

Comment: You would still need to have some criterion for distinguishing the `a` elements that should have the `target` attribute added from those that shouldn’t.

Comment: In this case with the small user base that has access to this input I am ok with the solution I've got. Thanks for the insight, however.

Comment: Who is voting to close everything these days? This is a perfectly reasonable, albiet easily searchable, question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a JavaScript-only way to accomplish this:

```
var nLink = $("div.notification-popup-message > a");

nLink.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.href);
});
```

Another method using querySelecterAll that actually adds the attribute to the HTML in the DOM:

```
var messageLink = document.querySelectorAll("div.message > a");

$(function() {
    $(messageLink).attr("target", "_blank");
});
```